# How to retrieve part of JSON file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

it's possible by using `IF` to retrieve some parts of JSON not all of it in **Objective-C**. like i want to retrieve just those  data when **Gender** equals **Male**

```
[
  {
    "name":"A",
    "gender":"Male",
    "age":20
  },
  {
    "name":"B",
    "gender":"Female",
    "age":12
  },
 {
    "name":"C",
    "gender":"Male",
    "age":20
  }
]
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative solution with NSPredicate

```
  NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"name\":\"A\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"age\":20},{\"name\":\"B\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"age\":12},{\"name\":\"C\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"age\":20}]";

  NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error: nil];
  NSArray *maleRecords = [jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender == 'Male'"]];
  NSLog(@"%@", maleRecords);
```

Comment: thank you @Vadian it works. but the result of maleRecords is like this `( { age = 20; gender = Male; name = A; }, { age = 20; gender = Male; name = C; } ) `which is not a JSON format and the first object moved to the last one and son on. **How can i those two issues** :-) –   i get this error when i want to populate it to UITableView  **-[__NSCFDictionary name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17407fd40**

Comment: you can't populate a table with pure json format, because it's just a string. You need an array of dictionaries. A dictionary is an object which contains unordered key value pairs. To get a value write `object[@"name"]` rather than `object.name`

Comment: @areeali That's the **description** of the dictionary object. It's just a normal `NSDictionary` which has string keys. It's **NOT TEXT,** because it has already been parsed. You can access its contents using subscript notation (e. g. `record[@"Name"]` or `[record objectForKey:@"Name"]`), but **please please please** don't ask trivially answerable questions like this. Instead **read the documentation** of the classes being used and **think about what happens** when you are parsing JSON.

Answer (score 2):

using for in loop

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in JSONArray) {
        if ([dict[@"gender"] isEqualToString:@"Male"]) {
            NSLog(@"Gender Data: Name = %@ Age = %@", dict[@"name"], dict[@"age"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, Figured I'd point out that you can use the modern syntax of `dict[@"gender]` as well, instead of `[dict valueForKey:@"gender"]`

Comment: true, I have used them in NSLog, I am editing it for the if condition as well

Comment: ah, didn't see that initially haha